# Add Days to Date is 1st Row of Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have 1st line of DataFrame as shown below.

I need to increment 7 days from df[1,17] till df[1,40]

I have written code like as follows

But it throws error

Please help

```
for(i in 1:23){
  
  test1[1,i + ncol(test1)] <- test1[1, ncol(test1)] + 7
  
}
```

error message:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, i + ncol(test1), value = 18917) :
> new columns would leave holes after existing columns

[image]

Comment: Show us your original dataframe.

Comment: Please don't upload code or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Hi Sir, there is no other way showing my dataframe as it is running into 1000's of line. And one member asked me to show the original DF

Comment: You can supply a sample extract. Also of the output you expect

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved error by creating empty columns in existing DF